# comunication between server, JavaFX desktop app and android app

Tags: java, android, json, grails, javafx

this is a theoric question.

I want to deploy an app, actually 3, that:
-Manage a database (SQLite) from the desktop, in JavaFX, Done!!
-Server/WebApp that sends data(JSON) to several android devices.(¿Grails??)
-Android App to recieve and manage the JSON (and more things).

My doubts are:
-In my desktop app when the user chilck the "Send info to device" 
    the app must do a call to the service app like `http://myserver/receiveJSONtoSend` and the server listen the  request and send the data to the device? and in the device recieve and do things with the JSON, and when the task are finished send other request to the server and the server comunicate to the desktop app. This is right?

-How the server comunicate with the desktop app? by suscribing like a listener?

Sorry abot my english and my non especific question, if some extra information is needed tell to me please!

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since Java is painfully object oriented its often a good idea to use a [JavaRMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) engine for Java to Java communication.

@mod: I see this as a comment, but can't put it there on my own. Thanks!